# WPF Frame.Navigate triggering multiple events

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a fairly new to WPF and C#.
I have a frame component on my main window and 4 buttons next to it that navigate to different views in the frame. Within one the the views there is a DataGrid that has a SelectionChanged event which makes an SQL call to a database that fetches records, whose data is then used to populate a list of custom objects (these relate to the selected item on the DataGrid).
Anyways, the problem I have is that from time to time multiple calls (2 or 3) to the SelectionChanged event are being triggered at the same time for a single selection change (mouseclick) on the DataGrid.

The navigation button click events on the main window all look like this:

```
    private void btn_MyDesk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/MyDeskView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void btn_AllOrders_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/AllOrdersView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

After some experiementation, I've found that the bug only happens after changing views away from the view with the DataGrid, and then changing back to it (but not always). When the bug appears the number of calls generally corresponds to the number of times I had switched views. Furthermore, the bug will simply vanish if leave the program alone for a minute or two. This makes me suspect that there multiple instances of the DataGrid view lingering like ghosts in memory and duplicating event calls until they are cleaned up by a garbage collector.

Should I be cleaning something up each time I switch views, or am I looking in the wrong place?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Edit: In answer to @Peter Moore
I subscribe to the event in the DataGrid declaration within the views XAML: SelectionChanged="dtg_MyDeskOrderGrid_SelectionChanged"

Edit: This is the sequence that happens on a selection change in the data grid. It includes several UI changes while the SQL records for the new selection are retrieved and displayed on a second DataGrid (dtg_MyDeskOrderItems). While the SQL call is being made, the relevant controls are disbaled and a semi-transparent panel (bdr_DGLoadingPanel) is moved on screen to cover them and display a loading animation. When the work is done, the work area is re-enabled and the loading panel moved off screen. Focus is also returned to the main "order" Datagrid.

dtg_MyDeskOrderGrid: This is the main DataGrid showing all "Orders"

dtg_MyDeskOrderItems: This is a secondary DataGrid that is updated to show all "Items" in the selected order.

```
    private void dtg_MyDeskOrderGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrSelectedOrder = (Order_class)dtg_MyDeskOrderGrid.SelectedItem;
        if (CurrSelectedOrder.ItemList == null) 
        {
            if (NowWorking == false)
            {
                NowWorking = true;
                bdr_DGLoadingPanel.Margin = new Thickness(2);
                dtg_MyDeskOrderGrid.IsEnabled = false;
                bdr_FilterPanel.IsEnabled = false;
                bdr_DGLoadingPanel.Focus();
                img_LoadingCircle.RenderTransform = rt;
                img_LoadingCircle.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);
                bdr_DGLoadingPanel.UpdateLayout();
                worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dtg_MyDeskOrderItems.ItemsSource = null;
            dtg_MyDeskOrderItems.ItemsSource = CurrSelectedOrder.ItemList;
            dtg_MyDeskOrderItems.Items.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object? sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        DatabaseConnection DBConn9 = new DatabaseConnection();
        DBConn9.FillOrderItems(CurrSelectedOrder);
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object? sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            dtg_MyDeskOrderItems.ItemsSource = null;
            dtg_MyDeskOrderItems.ItemsSource = CurrSelectedOrder.ItemList;
            dtg_MyDeskOrderItems.Items.Refresh();
            bdr_DGLoadingPanel.Margin = new Thickness(1000, 2, 2, 2);
            rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, null);
            dtg_MyDeskOrderGrid.IsEnabled = true;
            bdr_FilterPanel.IsEnabled = true;
            // The following work-around and accompanying GetDataGridCell function were used to give keyboard focus back to the datagrid to make navigation with arrow keys work again.
            // It appears keyboard focus is not returned to the Datagrid cells when using the Datagrid.focus() method.
            Keyboard.Focus(GetDataGridCell(dtg_MyDeskOrderGrid.SelectedCells[0]));
            NowWorking = false;
        });
    }
```

Edit...
Following the advice of the commentors, I was able to fix the bug by unsubscribing from the event in the Unloaded event for the view containing the DataGrid:

```
private void uct_MyDeskView_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dtg_MyDeskOrderGrid.SelectionChanged -= dtg_MyDeskOrderGrid_SelectionChanged;
    }
```

However, I was not able to reproduce the bug using a barebones testing project.

The UI in the original project is quite heavy, so I'm wondering if it's not the old view and events lingering in memory as this seems to fit the behavior of the bug & fix (Only occuring when I navigate away and back causing a new view to be created, multiple event triggers corresponding to the number of times I navigated away, and then finally the bug vanishing of its own accord after a moment or two).

I won't be settling on this as a final solution and instead will learn about ways I can reuse instances of my views (as suggested by Bionic) instead of recreating them. The reason for this is, if the SelectionChanged event is getting multiple triggers from old view instances, then it is likely other events will suffer from the same bug. This would be bad.

@BionicCode If you are still around, could you repost your initial comment as a solution so I can mark it answered?

Thank you to everyone for all the help and education. ^_^

Comment: You can consider to navigate by instance instead by URI. This way you can reuse the same instance. Navigating by URI will create a new instance of the view. Alternatively you should not subscribe to the SelectionChanged event. Instead you can bind to the DataGrid.SelectedItem and execute the action from the setter of the source property.

Comment: Almost certainly there are multiple subscriptions going on. How/when are you subscribing to SelectionChanged?

Comment: Agreed with @BionicCode re binding if you only support one item selected at a time. (unfortunately that isn't an option if you support multiple selection - a decades-old frustration)

Comment: If you can't use DataGrid.SelectedItem i.e. you have to listen to the SelectionChanged event then you must track navigation (there are several related events that are exposed by the Frame and the NavigationService) and unhook the event handler(s) of the discarded view instance.

Comment: @Peter Moore, I subscribe to the event in the DataGrid declaration within the views XAML: SelectionChanged="dtg_MyDeskOrderGrid_SelectionChanged"

Comment: @BionicCode, After your suggestion I have discovered the WPF Navigation Service. Should I study up on how to use that?

Comment: Ok. So what's weird is that even if there are lingering DaraGrid instances if they're off screen they shouldn't be getting mouse events. Are you ever SETTING the selection through code? But anyway I again agree with @BionicCode, subscribe (and UNSUBSCRIBE) to SelectionChanged during navigation as appropriate.

Comment: Pages can be kept alive. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.page.keepalive?view=windowsdesktop-7.0 You might set that true and ensure you retain the instance of your page in memory. Selectionchanged can happen as your datagrid is torn down and it can even fire as a row loses focus.  I would suggest an entirely different approach but it's a lengthier explanation than most newbies would be interested in.

Comment: This selectionchange is subscribed in your page, right? So that doesn't know about any navigation.

Comment: @PeterMoore Possibly. I'm still new, so I'm not 100% sure what secondary events are being triggered during the SQL call and object loading squence. I'll include the code for the squence in the orginal post.

Comment: This selectionchanged will likely be interfered with by any debug step through. If you debug,writeline to console. What's it change to?  Could you just check value and ignore change to last value or null? Or selectedindex -1

Comment: Also. Selectionchanged is a routed event. It could be firing from a child of the control you handle it on.

Comment: Jaydek thanks for the extra context. The mystery remains why off-screen DGs would be sending SelectoinChange's but it does look like you're only allowing one SelectedItem at a time, so I would go back to @bioniccode's original suggestion and just two-way bind to SelectedItem and call your DB code in the bound setter. And make sure to check that you're actually getting a new value!

Comment: @PeterMoore Well I feel I am much wiser thanks to all the information you, Bionic and andy have posted. I have several leads I can now study up on and one will surely work out. I'll post how it goes later. Right now it is almost 10pm and my head is aching, lol.

Comment: See this  Keyboard.Focus(GetDataGridCell(dtg_MyDeskOrderGrid.SelectedCells[0]));  I wonder if that fires selectionchanged.

Comment: If the itemlist becomes null then anything previously selected would not be. That would also fire selectionchanged.  You should use different techniques in several places here.

Comment: How are you navigating to trigger the issue? Using the back and forward buttons of the Frame will create a new instance of the view but will restore the state (to provide a navigation history without storing the full Page). This leads to the raising of the SelectionChanged event. Using the NavigationService has the big advantage that the Page does not need a reference to the Frame when it wants to navigate (every Page exposes a NavigationService too).

Comment: If you need more input, posting a complete minimal example that reproduces the issue would be helpful. From what you show (navigating by Frame.Navigate) should not produce the issue (restoring of the previous state for a new Page instance). If the issue is not triggered by using the Frame navigation buttons, then you overlooked some important details. That's why a minimal working example would be helpful.

Comment: @BionicCode I could be misreading but I think his multiple SelectionChange firings are happening just on a simple mouse click of a row, not just during navigations. That's why I can't understand why even if there's zombie DataGrid's still in memory how are they getting those mouse clicks? My suspicion is that the zombie DG's are firing SelectionChange's not from mouse clicks but from manual selection changes somewhere in the OP's code that we haven't seen yet.

Comment: @PeterMoore That's why I asked for a complete minimal example. Also while figuring out how to reproduce it, he will likely identify the cause. What  he's experiencing is not normal but it is not explainable by the posted code. Maybe he navigates before the BackgroundWorker has completed. This could explain it. Because after completion he modifies the DataGrid which will change the current selection.

Comment: Yep, agreed @BionicCode

Comment: Maybe you navigate before the BackgroundWorker has completed? This could explain it. Because after completion you modify the DataGrid which will change the current selection. I should also mention that BackgroundWorker is an obsolete way to post background work. You should consider to use Task.Run instead (or async/await in general). Also the RunWorkerCompleted event is already raised on the UI thread, what makes the Dispatcher.Invoke redundant.

Comment: @BionicCode I think you're onto something! I tested if changing `IsEnabled` always fires `SelectionChanged` and it does not. I wonder if it has something to do with giving the cell focus. I couldn't reproduce that either but perhaps if we see more of the code it'll be clear.

Comment: I was able to completely fix the bug by unsubscribing form the event in the Unloaded event for the view. I've posted an update in an edit above. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Note also that you'd be keeping your page in memory with the this.Dispatcher.Invoke((). Until the dispatcher actions that, the page cannot be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of the commentors, I was able to initially fix the bug by unsubscribing from the event in the Unloaded event for the view containing the DataGrid:

```
private void uct_MyDeskView_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dtg_MyDeskOrderGrid.SelectionChanged -= dtg_MyDeskOrderGrid_SelectionChanged;
    }
```

However as this solution only disconnected the one event and didn't solve the root problem of old views lingering in the background and firing events before being cleaned up, I finally went the following code that keeps only one instance of my view in memory and reuses it.

```
private MyDeskView? currMyDeskView = null;

private void btn_MyDesk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currMyDeskView == null)
        {
            currMyDeskView = new MyDeskView();
        }
        MainFrame.Navigate(currMyDeskView);
    }
```

Thank you to everyone who helped me get over this bug.